# Black screen on running the code

Tags: android, andengine, sprite

I'm trying to understand sprites in andEngine. I wrote the below code to load a simple image "img"

```
package com.example.pxc;

import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.source.IBitmapTextureAtlasSource;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.buildable.builder.BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.buildable.builder.ITextureAtlasBuilder.TextureAtlasBuilderException;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.ITextureRegion;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.SimpleBaseGameActivity;

public class TestActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {

    static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
    static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
    BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas bbta;
    ITextureRegion msr;
    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        Camera mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED,
            new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreateResources() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
         bbta = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(mEngine.getTextureManager(), 256, 256);  
        msr=BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(bbta, this, "img.png");
        try{
        bbta.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(0, 1, 1));
        bbta.load();

                } catch (TextureAtlasBuilderException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }       
    }

    @Override
    protected Scene onCreateScene() {
        Scene scene = new Scene();
        Sprite mSprite = new Sprite(0, 0,
                msr, mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        scene.attachChild(mSprite);
        return scene;
    }
}
```

The above code compiles without any errors. When i run the code, i get to see a black screen on the emulator instead of the image. Why this happens? and how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: It may be because of  your emulator is not supporting gles2.Look at my post it may help you

Comment: how big is img.png? I suspect your TextureAtlas may not be large enough to hold the image. I think if the issue were the emulator settings, it would just error out, not show a black screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run on Emulator first you have to provide settings as shown in [this link](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/how-to-get-emulator-working-t9456.html)
If you want effective  one to get good fps then following  [link](http://www.matim-dev.com/fast-emulator.html) may help you